# Is there a default password for Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I recently started playing around with a Debian google cloud platform instance. After I was away from my PC overnight, it went into lock mode and asked me for a password. Given I never set a password, is there a default one I should know, or is my instance dead already?

Comment: It looks to me from the Cloud offerings that it just uses your Gmail password.

Comment: Surely you read [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance), right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the comment to your question is the right answer as,

**Cloud used your Gmail's password as its password**

I verified this for my own Ubuntu VM instance up and running.